# Find an open bounded set which is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to find an open bounded set which is not Jordan-measurable, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan-measurable, if $A$ is bounded and $\partial A$ is a Lebesgue nullset. A Lebesgue nullset is defined as follows: $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue nullset if
$$ \forall \varepsilon >0\hspace{0,1cm}\exists (Q_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ a family of rectangles so that: }A\subset \bigcup_{k=1} Q_k  \text{  and } V_n\left(\bigcup_{k=1} Q_k\right)< \varepsilon, \text{ where } V_n \text{ is the Jordan measure given by } V_n(A)=\int_{Q} \mathbb{1}_A dx \text{  for some } A\subset Q \text{ rectangle }.$$

Let $(q_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Then the set
$$ B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(q_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},q_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
is open and obviously

$$ B\subset \left[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4}\right].$$
Moreover
$$\mathbb{R}\cap [0,1]=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap [0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} {q_n}\subset \overline{B}\subset \left[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4}\right].$$

Does the latter help me to find a rectangle $Q$ such that $Q\subset \partial B$ or is it possible to obtain $\partial B$ in some more efficient way?

Comment: You need to define $$B_\epsilon= \bigcup_n \left(q_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},q_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$ Then show that $\epsilon$ can be chosen with $|B_\epsilon| < 1$ Since $[0,1] \setminus B_\epsilon \subseteq \overline B_\epsilon \setminus B_\epsilon = \partial B_\epsilon$, this means $\partial B_\epsilon$ cannot be a null set.